# How to have sorting functionality with Plotly tables?

Tags: sorting, plotly, plotly-python

I have created a data table using Plotly from pandas dataframe. I want to know if there's a way we can add sorting functionality when clicking on the header of the table? My sample code is as below:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'City':['A','C','B'], 'Population':[552,658,423]})
fig= go.Figure(data=[go.Table(header=dict(values=list(df.columns), align='center',font=dict(family='Segoe UI',color='black', size=12)), cells=dict(values=df.transpose().values.tolist(), align='center', font=dict(family='Segoe UI',color='black', size=12)))])
fig.show()
```

Any help/lead on this will be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: hi @PyPyVk, this question is a little too broad the way it's written: you're asking for sorting functionality and heatmap color coded cells which are both features that are involved enough to be two separate questions. if you update your question to ask about only sorting functionality, I'd be happy to vote to reopen your question (as i'm sure others would be too)

Comment: thanks for updating your question- I voted to reopen it